# Get inside docker container

Tags: безопасность, docker

Допустим наш докер контейнер был запущен на удаленном хосте, которым мы не управляем, может ли этот хост нарушить изоляцию и влезть внутрь контейнера? Что бы допустим изменить работу приложения и посылать нам неверные данные?

Answer (score 1):

В докер можно получить доступ следующим вариантом:

```
$ sudo docker attach 665b4a1e17b6 #by ID
```

или

```
$ sudo docker attach loving_heisenberg #by Name

$ root@665b4a1e17b6:/#
```

Или начиная с docker -v >1.3

```
$ sudo docker exec -i -t 665b4a1e17b6 /bin/bash #by ID
```

или

```
$ sudo docker exec -i -t loving_heisenberg /bin/bash #by Name
$ root@665b4a1e17b6:/#
```

Привожу реальный пример из опыта.
В нашей конторе настроено CI/CD система , сначала проводится билд контейнера , потом через выше указанные команды подключаемся в контейнер, и запускаем тесты (внутри контейнера). 
После удачного билда и тестов , мы пушим изменения в закрытую ветку , и уже приватный докер-репозиторий проводит билд , и по тригеру отправляет запрос в архистратор для перезапуска сервиса с этим контейнером.
Так вот суть такова что иногда где-то забыл константу или чтото копеечное , мы заходим в сам контейнер на сервере, и от туда уже уже через `nano` мы меняем конфиг или мелкий баг , чтоб не проводить всю цепочку заново , и просто перезапускаем. В итоге код поменян , и никто об этом не узнает. Но если вы скачаете новый имедж , или же удалите сам контейнер . То все вернется в изначальное состояние.
Ну и иногда приходится там же и код писать =) Поскольку, есть куча статы базы там же и все сервисы , дев сервер он на то и рассчитан. 
А по сабжу :

> Допустим наш докер контейнер был запущен на удаленном хосте, которым мы не управляем, может ли этот хост нарушить изоляцию и влезть внутрь контейнера?

**ДА**

> Что бы допустим изменить работу приложения и посылать нам неверные
>   данные?

**ДА**